# Error: instance profile is required to re-create mounting cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm attempting to run a `terraform_plan` in my prod environment, but I receive the following error:

```
│ Error: instance profile is required to re-create mounting cluster
│ 
│   with databricks_mount.gfc_databricks_delta_lake,
│   on gfc_mount_delta_lake.tf line 1, in resource "databricks_mount" "gfc_databricks_delta_lake":
│    1: resource "databricks_mount" "gfc_databricks_delta_lake" {
│ 
╵
```

Here's the code for the mount:

```
resource "databricks_mount" "gfc_databricks_delta_lake" {
  depends_on = [
    databricks_cluster.gfc_automation_cluster, 
    databricks_instance_profile.gfc_instance_profile
  ]
  provider   = databricks.workspace_00
  name       = "gfc"
  cluster_id = databricks_cluster.gfc_automation_cluster.id
  s3 {
    bucket_name = "XXX"
  }
}
```

This code, along with the code for the instance profiles and automation clusters, is identical between our dev and prod environment. Still, the error only pops up in prod.

What's puzzling is that the `databricks_mount` is pointed to a cluster that already has an instance profile. The instance profile exists in the Terraform state file, Databricks, and AWS.

One thing that's strange is that the cluster that's supposed to be using that instance profile is missing from Databricks, but is present in the state file. Could be a clue.

Comment: file github issue for databricks provider... but mounting cluster should be recreated if it's missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DATABRICKS_HOST` and `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` environment variables.
You can add the following lines to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to automatically set these values as environment variables when you open up a new terminal session

```
export DATABRICKS_HOST="insert_databricks_workspace_url"
export DATABRICKS_TOKEN="insert_databricks_api_token"
```

Per Databricks Provider Terraform Documentation,

You can use host and token parameters to supply credentials to the workspace. When environment variables are preferred, then you can specify DATABRICKS_HOST and DATABRICKS_TOKEN instead. Environment variables are the second most recommended way of configuring this provider.

[source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-hostname-and-token)